# hadoop example jobs failing with networking error

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I am running a test cluster of three nodes (one real system, two virtual machines). All three ubuntu 10.1 or higher.
Hadoop version 1.0.2 and hive 0.8.1

Now, basic things are working fine, nodes are able to talk to each other, packets are being replicated and all that. processes are running fine.

As a testcase, I tried to run the standard hadoop word count example. That map/reduce job fails saying -

```
Call to <my_NameNode_HostName>127.0.0.1:9000 failed on connection exception:
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Though the job continues, sometimes it just hangs, other times, it repeats this message (and stacktrace of course) few times before failing.  Surprisingly, no output is produced, either on screen or in the output directory.

Here's the command that I run -

```
hadoop jar hadoop*examples*.jar wordcount /text_data /txt_output
```

hadoop is in path, the jar files are available in the current directory, and 3 text files have been copied into hdfs directory /text_data

Googling also doesnt seem to find something useful.. seeking help here...

Edit:
I forgot to add that the other jobs (e.g. triggered by hive queries) are running just fine.
the SSH is setup across the three nodes, and all the edges have been tested for connectivity without password challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem is with the NameNode. Is your name node up ?

I will try below to identify the issue:

1) Try jps at master node to see name node daemon is running
2) Verify the logs of name node hadoop/logs/
3) verify /etc/hosts/ configuration and masters file configuration

Comment: yep, jps has been tried on namenode and on other two nodes, all of them are reported up.  Will go back to the namenode logs and share info.